# javafx Bindings: Text bind to two properties

Tags: java, javafx

I want to bind the text property of a Text Node to two properties like this:

```
Text income = new Text();
income.textProperty().bind(Bindings.concat(Available.income.asString()).concat(" Income for ").concat(now.getValue().getMonth().toString()));
```

[image]

Now, when Available.income changes, the Text node reflect the update, BUT when 'now' changes Nothing happens;

```
public static SimpleIntegerProperty income = new SimpleIntegerProperty
private ObjectProperty<YearMonth> now = new SimpleObjectProperty<YearMonth>(YearMonth.now());
```

how can i solve this, Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do

```
income.textProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> 
    available.income.get() + " Income for " + now.getValue().getMonth(),
    available.income, now));
```